# NSDateFormatter Always NIL in stringFromDate !? (iOS 8.0)

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Okay, i already have been going through about 20 threads. I checked everything locale, timezone, whatever .. Nothing.

I tried to Copy whole Snippets where the people said they are working but they aren't working for me ?!

This comes from the Server: 2015-02-25T21:48+02:00

I did the following. I have a UIViewController and In the ViewDidLoad I do the following:

```
mDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[mDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZ"];
```

And later on in the TableView I try to get the String out of a NSDate. And really looked into it and it is surely a NSDate and not an NSString.

```
date = [mDateFormat stringFromDate:order.date];
NSLog(date);
NSLog([order.date description]);
NSDate *dd = [mDateFormat dateFromString:@"2014-10-15T00:00+02:00"];
NSLog([dd description]);
```

Date is a NSString and date is always nil.

The NSLog from order.date returns: 2015-02-25T21:57+01:00
The NSLog from dd returns: 2014-10-14 22:00:00 +0000

I don't know how to solve this. I am already working 1-2 Hours on it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong. See the [Unicode Technical Standard #35-31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) which is the one [used by iOS 7 and above](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

`ZZZ` is a format like `-0800` (*without* the `:`). You want `ZZZZZ` (5 Z) to support the colon, as in `-08:00`. So the correct format should be:

```
[mDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"];
```

Comment: I am sorry. That doesnt work. Date Format is now : [mDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"];

Comment: You still get the same output?

Comment: Yeah the other Outputs are still working. But the String date is still nil.

Comment: You mean, the output of `[mDateFormat stringFromDate:order.date]` is `nil`, even though `order.date` is a valid date? What about `[mDateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]`?

Comment: Then the problem is with your `order.date`. I bet it's either `nil` or not a `NSDate`. Put this right before the `[mDateFormat stringFromDate:order.date]` line: `NSLog(@"%@", [order.date class]);` What does that print?

Comment: You are right. But someone said in a Thread, when there is a Timezone it has to be a NSDate and not an NSString. I am sorry. Thank you.

Comment: Nah, as the name and type of argument already tell you, you *must* pass a `NSDate` to `stringFromDate:`. That method is "intelligent" enough to not crash if you feed it garbage, you just get `nil` in this case :-) A crash might be better, though: it would have immediately told you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue with NSDateFormatter on iOS8. When trying to retrieve a NSDate with dateFromString, nil is always returned. It's all about iOS Region Format setting. Change that to another region then back to your region settings. That might be a bug on iOS8.

Comment: It's a bug in your code. Set the locale to en_US_POSIX and it will work

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasBauch!